# Accessing EE data via iOS swift

Tags: ajax, ee3, json, authentication, rest

Good afternoon,

I have a bit of a noob question here.  I'm learning swift, and I'd like to write an application to access (read only at first) data from my EE3 site.  All the good data I'm hoping to access is locked behind logins for members.

I've read a number of terms, but I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction on what I should study up on first?

REST?  JSON?  AJAX?  XID_CODE?

I understand I'll probably using a swift NSURLSession call along with some authentication.

Really appreciate anyone's thoughts here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

EE doesn't have a native API interface to communicate with, but I've been having quite a good time with [Webservice API plugin from Reinos](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/webservice), and with it you can turn a EE install into a REST/XMLRPC/SOAP server. They've also done the hard work of connecting with many third-party add-ons. Check [out the docs here.](http://docs.reinos.nl/webservice/)

Comment: Interesting.  But for full functionality (all the various modules), it's almost $200.  That seems really high for a would-be-neat project.

Comment: You only need the main plugin for any kind of crud ... EE3 really flies in a headless environment